# Default Bit value is null instead of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simple problem, I've created Default value for columne "isThere" set to 1, but when I insert new records (I include all columns except "isThere") all of them have "isThere" set to null.

Here is my constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projects] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Projects]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [isThere]
GO
```

Comment: [I can't replicate your problem.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=febda09ce0b827188cd1c1b2baed9600). If, however, you don't want `NULL` stored why not set your column to `NOT NULL` as well?

Comment: Please post your INSERT statement as well.

Comment: You've created a default for the column named `Active`, not `isThere`. This may just be a typo, or it may be the cause of your problem...

Comment: Why is your constraint on Active, but you are expecting column isThere to be affected?

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's a typo, it's "isThere" in real script

Comment: Think it's time to post that `INSERT` statement so that we can **replicate** your problem. As I've shown, with the small information we have, we can't replicate it.

Comment: Then, per @Larnu, you need to post your `INSERT`, possibly capturing it in Profiler first if you're not using explicit `INSERT` statements, and also checking for any triggers that may gum up the works. Something in the background may just be explicitly inserting `NULL` values for the column, which is permitted even with a default.

Comment: I used LINQ in C# to import data and I can see now that the passed value for "isThere" is null even though I didn't set it. I guess I will manually change it to "1" in C# for each record. Thanks guys for help.

Comment: @MartinSmith dur....thanks for the reminder. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LINQ in C# to import data and I can see now that the passed value for "isThere" is null even though I didn't set it. I need to manually set it to "1" for each record.